# ignore known vulnerability in npm audit

Tags: security, quill, npm-audit, cve

`npm audit` is part of my Bitbucket pipeline. I use [quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) which introduces an [XSS vulnerability](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3364). It was shipped via cdn, but now my app serves this dependency itself. `npm audit` now fails because of the XSS.

I am not sure yet if this vulnerability is even relevant to my use case. But I would like to be able to suppress a vulnerability in `npm audit`. I tried `better-npm-audit`, but it doesn`t seem to be able to generate json output needed for the pipeline.

I am confused because it feels like an obvious thing to suppress false positives. But googling around (and also asking chatgpt for help) didn't help.

So: is it possible to suppress false positives in `npm audit`?

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same thing. We are currently experiencing a dev dependency that has a security vulnerability, this isn't fixable and naturally it is not that important since it is a dev dependency. Keen to see if you figure it out!